# Deploying java client, RabbitMQ, and Celery to server

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, message-queue, task-queue

I have a Java API on my server, and I want it to create tasks and add them to Celery via RabbitMQ. I followed the following tutorial, http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html, where I used java for the client (send.java) and python to receive (receive.py). In receive.py, where the callback method is invoked, I call a method that I've annotated with @celery.task so that the task is added to celery.

I'm wondering how all of this is deployed on a server though, specifically, why there is a receive.py file. Is receive.py a process that must continually run on the server? Is there a way to configure RabbitMQ so that it automatically routes java client tasks to celery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**RabbitMQ** is just a message queue. Producers put messages and consumers get them on demand. You can only restrict access for specific queues via **RabbitMQ**'s auth options.

As for deployment: yes, `receive.py` needs to continuously run. It is **Celery**'s job to do that. See the [Workers Guide](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html) for info on running a **worker**.